# After parsing CSV as an array of objects can't access some property

Tags: javascript, node.js

After parsing CSV:

```
id,x
1,0.358995018
2,0.196424349
3,0.882696509
4,0.765233761
5,0.25087529
```

with code

```
let lines = data.split('\n');
            let props = lines.shift().split(',');
            let objects = [];
            for (let line of lines) {
                let values = line.split(',');
                let obj = {};
                for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++)
                    obj[props[i]] = isNaN(values[i]) ? values[i] : parseFloat(values[i]);
                objects.push(obj);
            }
            this.data = objects;
```

can't access last property of any object and for some reason it's double quoted in debugger...
What's going on?

[can't access property "x"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yN8u.png)

Comment: `obj['\"x\"']` should work. can you right click on that object in debugger and copy it and paste it here?

Comment: **First theory:** maybe the `x` is not actually an `x` but another [**unicode character**](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/x) that looks like `x` (probably just an uppercased `X`), to find out check if `props[1].charCodeAt(0) === 120`. **Second theory:** there may be some hidden characters in `props[1]` like `\t`, `\r`..., to find out check if `props[1].length === 1`.

Answer (score 0):

When putting your code in a snippet I do not have this problem. Perhaps it is a problem with how your data is formatted or how you are accessing the object?

See the snippet below.

```js
var data = 
`id,x
1,0.358995018
2,0.196424349
3,0.882696509
4,0.765233761
5,0.25087529`;

var dataToObj = function(data) {
  let lines = data.split('\n');
  let props = lines.shift().split(',');
  let objects = [];
  for (let line of lines) {
      let values = line.split(',');
      let obj = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++)
          obj[props[i]] = isNaN(values[i]) ? values[i] : parseFloat(values[i]);
      objects.push(obj);
  }
  return objects; 
}


console.log(dataToObj(data)[0].x);
```